# How to make a for loop to find the average of the columns in several data frames and add a new column?

Tags: r, for-loop

I looked at the variations of this question, but was not able to find an answer that worked...so here goes. I have a lot of data frames, each representing a psychological index (the kind where they ask several questions and the average of them all gives you a score on what it is that you are measuring (anger, anxiety, etc). For this example, I will choose three of them: SA, SE, GT

I would like to make a for loop to automatically calculate the average of the columns in each data frame, and then add a new column with that average.

I was able to make a for loop to do this for one data frame, but how do I then loop this loop to do it for all of my data frames (which is a lot more than 3)?

```
#This is the for loop to do it for just one data frame (SA)
avg <- c()
for(i in 1:nrow(SA)){
  avg[i] <- (sum(as.numeric(SA[i,]), na.rm =T)/ncol(SA))
}
SA$avg <- avg


#This is what I tried to do for multiple:
my.list <- list(SA, SE, GT)

for(l in my.list){
 avg <- c()
  for(i in 1:nrow(l)){
  avg[i] <- (sum(as.numeric(l[i,]), na.rm =T)/ncol(l))
}
l$avg <- avg
}
```

Comment: Can you make your question [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) so that it is easier to help you ?

Answer (score 1):

This may work for you. I've created some dummy data frames, assuming that you have the same number of observations for each psychological index. You then bash them all together into one big dataframe. The colMeans function will compute means for each column:

```
SA <- data.frame(SA=runif(10))
SE <- data.frame(SE=runif(10))
GT <- data.frame(GT=runif(10))
MP <- data.frame(MP=runif(10))
df <- cbind(SA, SE, GT, MP)
av <- colMeans(df, na.rm = TRUE)
```

If the indices have differing numbers of observations, you can combine them into a list as you did, and then use the function sapply(). Since each element of the list is a dataframe, you need to extract the actual column by using the index operator [, 1] (first column):

```
df <- list(SA, SE, GT, MP)
sapply(df, function(x) mean(x[,1], na.rm=TRUE))
```

**UPDATE**:
You can create a list of your dataframes again, but as you need means across rows, just use the rowMeans() function:

```
SA <- data.frame(matrix(runif(50), nrow=10))
SE <- data.frame(matrix(runif(80), nrow=10))
df <- list(SA, SE)
lapply(df, function(x) {x$index_means <- rowMeans(x, na.rm=TRUE); return(x) })
```

This will give you a list of data frames with a new column of means for each index.

Comment: Is there a way to then quickly overwrite all of the individual data frames to include that new column? I was able to do it for one by storing that lapply function in a variable (df1) and then doing SA <- data.frame(df1[1]), but ideally I'd like to use a function of some kind

Comment: Please try the code: it creates a new list of dataframes comprising the old data but with a new column added called index_means. Isn't that what you want?